# Can you write to specific indexes of an Array in java?

Tags: java

So I'm trying to load actor models, and eventually this class is going to get pretty big. So I really don't want to have to keep track of writing them all to my entity array(line 40), is there a more efficient way of storing my actor models. using indexing?

My code looks like this..

```
12.    public static Entity[] callActors(Loader loader) {
13.
14.     //Earth Entity Actor        
15.     model = OBJLoader.loadObjModel("moon", loader);
16.     texture = new ModelTexture(loader.loadTexture("MoonMap1024x1024"));
17.     staticModel = new TexturedModel(model,texture);
18.     texture = staticModel.getTexture();
19.     texture.setShineDamper(10);
20.     texture.setReflectivity(0);
21.     //Assigned an Entity Actor
22.     Entity entity1 = new Entity(staticModel, new Vector3f(-1.40f,1,-6.0f),0,0,0,1);     
23.     
...
39.
40.      Entity[] entityArray = {entity1,entity2,entity3};
41.     
42.     return entityArray;
43. }
```

Is there a way to use indexing like this at line 22 
`Entity[] entityArray[1] = new Entity(staticModel, new Vector3f(-1.40f,1,-6.0f),0,0,0,1);`
instead of writing all of the actors to the entity array all at once (line 40)?

Comment: `Entity[] entityArray = {entity1,entity2,entity3};` is effectively the same as `Entity[] entityArray = new Entity[3]; entityArray[0] = new Entity(staticModel, new ...etc); entityArray[1] = new ...etc`, if that is what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare array of type Entity with specific size and add elements in it using indexing. You can also maintain index variable.

```
 Entity[] arr = new Entity[10];
 arr [0]= new Entity(staticModel, new Vector3f(-1.40f,1,-6.0f),0,0,0,1);
```

OR

```
Entity[] arr = new Entity[10];
int i=0;
 arr [i]= new Entity(staticModel, new Vector3f(-1.40f,1,-6.0f),0,0,0,1);
 i++;
 arr [i]= new Entity(staticModel, new Vector3f(-1.40f,1,-6.0f),0,0,0,1);
 i++;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Also, do I have to declare this knowing the final size of my Array?

Comment: @TheSpiceHoarder, If you use array, you need to know the final size. On the other hand, if the size varies, you may try `ArrayList` instead.

Comment: @TheSpiceHoarder, to use array we have to declare it's size. If size is unpredictable the we can use ArrayList instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I got you right, but if you want easy way to init the array you can do it like this:

```
Entity[] arr = new Entity[] {entity1, entity2, enttiy3};
```

If you want to set specific indexes you can use `hashMap` (also get operations will be faster), do it like this:

```
HashMap<Integer, Entitiy> Entity = new HashMap<Integer, Entitiy>();
```

Useful links:

[HashMap in Java](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/hashmap-in-java-with-example/)

[Arrays in java](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arrays.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to use indexing like this at 
line 22
**Entity[] entityArray[1] = new Entity(staticModel, new Vector3f(-1.40f,1,-6.0f),0,0,0,1);** 
instead of writing all of the actors to the entity array all at once (line 40)?

You need not use the array symbol (**[ ]**) while trying to access one Entity. Since entityArray[1] means one Entity (stored at the position 1 in array entityArray), you can simply write:

```
Entity[] entityArray = new Entity[ARRAY_SIZE];
entityArray[1] = new Entity(staticModel, new Vector3f(-1.40f,1,-6.0f),0,0,0,1);
```

If you want, however, to construct the Data Structure after you have initialized your Entities, you can use the same code you've written.